# Is it OK to give status 404 to unauthorized users?

Tags: 404, best-practices, 403-forbidden, github

In recent months I have come across several sites, which give a 404 status/error page, when there should be 403 or maybe 401.

For example, I have a private repository on *github.com* with link:

https://github.com/BlueGhost-cz/BG3

When I accidentaly logged out and tried to reach this link, I only got **"This is not the page you are looking for"** message, which is obviously not true. I AM looking for it and the resource DOES exist, I am just not authenticated. I would expect a 403 or some other "permission denied" page. This one really scared me for a few seconds, because it implied my repository was deleted.

Do you also consider this to be wrong? What would be the "best practice" in this area?

Comment: My opinion is that when user is trying to reach authorized page, I would redirect him to login form and then, after authentication, if he had the rights to view the restricted content, I would redirect him back to his originally requested URL. Do you agree?

Comment: "This is not the page you are looking for" - was this also accompanied by a 404 status?

Comment: I wonder if this is a new trend some developers are inventing to try to eliminate bad robots and if so, I wonder how well it works.

Comment: @w3d - There is 404 both as a header of that page and a status of the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I think this is justified. By returning a 403 instead, Github would be confirming that a repository with that name exists, which in itself could be seen as a security hole (or at least undesirable).

As a contrived example, imagine that these repositories existed:

- http://github.com/valve/HalfLife
- http://github.com/valve/HalfLife2

If one day http://github.com/valve/HalfLife3 started returning a 403, that would basically confirm that Half Life 3 was being worked on.

The flip side of this is that it's not uncommon for web servers to be configured to serve 403s for non existent URLs, for the same reason.

Comment: Certainly a valid argument for a 404. However, I don't think it's necessarily _always_ appropriate to send a 404 - it depends on the site. If you are serving a login prompt for unauthorised access then a 403/401 would be more appropriate.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I was about to say that existance of the URL itself does not pose a security threat, since it doesn't give away the username of the owner, but your example somewhat justifies this. Even though I can't imagine someone, wanting to hide a secret project from the public, giving an exact name to the repository, instead of a code name.

Anyway, would be interesting to hear from the GitHub devs, what is actually the reason for this :)

Comment: Don't agree with this. It first should check if you have permissions to even know, if the repo exists or not. First Authorization, then 200 || 404

Answer (score 2):

Well, 404 should be used when the resource do not exist, is not that  you're not authorized, it is not there at all. 403 should be for forbidden resources, regardless you're authenticated, you might not have permission over a given resource. I rather 401 for resources that are found but requires some sort of authentication to get it. IMO

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about when the user has not yet logged in?

If the user has not yet logged in, then:

From [Celada](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/28804/celada) in response to a closely related question [Should I use a 404 or a 403 error for secure content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49576/should-i-use-a-404-or-a-403-error-for-secure-content):

- Use status 401 if you are using the authentication method built into HTTP. The 401 status code is what they tells the user's browser to prompt the user for their username and password. If you do not return 401, then the user's browser will never prompt your user to login.
- If you are using some other kind of authentication (e.g. session cookie), 401 is never used: usually 403 is used instead.

If the user is logged in but is not authorized to access the content (for example a regular user trying to access features only available to an administrator), then you should use the [403 Forbidden response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403).

Receiving a 403 response is the server telling you, “I’m sorry. I know who you are–I believe who you say you are–but you just don’t have permission to access this resource. Maybe if you ask the system administrator nicely, you’ll get permission. But please don’t bother me again until your predicament changes.”

See [Is HTTP code 401 or 403 appropriate for when a logged in user is not allowed to view the data?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90651/is-http-code-401-or-403-appropriate-for-when-a-logged-in-user-is-not-allowed-to?newreg=4ebfb189532a4f9c905ca226d2bfb484) [Mani](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/49436/mani) did a good job of explaining the use of 403 when a user lacks authorization to access a given feature or content.